# How to know the shape of the input X which is a placeholder in TF

Tags: tensorflow

I have the code:

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])
W = tf.variable...
....
Z ...
```

Z is a tensor and calculated from X, here I would like to know the batch size of Z, i.e., the first element value of Z, I have tried 
    Z.get_shape()[0].value and tf.shape(Z)[0]. Both results are None, How to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did it help or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here an example of how u can get it:

```
z = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(2, 3, 4)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(tf.shape(z))
```

since everything in TF is in a session  you need to run the session to excute the function you want to run !

Comment: Because the shape size is for my building the graph. while once I create the Session, I cannot build the graph but execute..